# How do I allocate size for a dynamic array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, size, allocation

So I wrote a method in c++ where I remove a range of elements in an array. The thing is this is a dynamic array and the size of the array must always be a certain size. So if I remove alot of elements from the array and leave at least 5 empty spaces then I need to remove those 5 empty spaces. I already wrote a similar method where I remove one element. This is the line that checks to see if there's too much space:

```
if (size - 1 == allocated_size - BLOCK_SIZE){
```

Where size is the number of elements in the array, allocated_size is how much space is in the array and BLOCK_SIZE is 5. So with my other remove method, I need to do a similar check however what if I have an array of 15 elements and I remove 10 elements. Then I would have to remove 10 spaces in the array but I'm not sure how to do that. Here's what I have right now:

```
if (size - range <= allocated_size - BLOCK_SIZE){
            try {
                new_array = new int[allocated_size - BLOCK_SIZE];
            } catch (bad_alloc){
                throw exception (MEMORY_EXCEPTION);
            }
```

Where range is the number of elements I'm removing. My theory is that maybe I could make another variable and when I declare the array I say allocated_size - BLOCK_SIZE * n so if I need to remove 10 spaces then n would be 2. The problem I'm having trouble implementing that.

Comment: `an array of 15 elements and I remove 10 elements.`.....`if I need to remove 10 spaces then n would be 2` . So 15 -10 = 2 ? I didn't expect that.

Comment: No that's not what I'm saying. The two comes from the amount of memory I have to delete. So if I need to free up 10 blocks of memory then I would use BLOCK_SIZE * 2 which equals 10 because BLOCK_SIZE is 5 so 5 * 2 = 10. The problem I'm having is telling the program that we need to free up 10 blocks of memory. Do you now understand what I'm asking?

Comment: Bascially I check to see how many spaces I have to free up. If I have to free up 5 spaces then n will be 1. If i have to free up 10 spaces then n will be 2. If I have to free up 15 spaces then n will be 3. The reason is because BLOCK_SIZE is set to 5 and that variable will always be 5. Therefore 5 * 3 will be 15. Same thing with 20. 5 * 4 is 20 so if I want to remove 20 spaces then n will be 4. I do not think I can explain anymore clearer than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use some int arithmetic,

the number of empty slots in your array will be:

```
int empty_slots = allocated_size - size;
```

The number of empty blocks will be:

```
int empty_blocks = empty_slots / 5;
```

integer division truncates so for 0 - 4 empty slots you will have 0 empty blocks for 5-9 empty slots you will have 1 empty block etc...

But don't you really want to know how big to make your new array? wouldn't that always be size, so:

```
int blocks_need = size / 5;                // truncates 
if (size % 5 > 0) {
    blocks_need = blocks_needed + 1;   // add a block if needed
}   
new_array = new int[blocks_needed * 5];
```

or size + extra capacity if you want some extra capacity in your array.

Comment: The thing about the new_array is that the allocated_size must always be a multiple of 5.

Comment: okay, so again just do some math, blocks_needed = size / 5; plus you will need one more block if there is a remainder when you divide size by 5, so if (size % 5) add one to blocks_needed